# LINQ to SQL nights between two dates for every month

Tags: c#, sql, linq, date

In DB I have a collection of BookingRooms which contains Checkin and Checkout date lets say:

ID  |   Checkin   |   Checkout

1   |  01/01/2017 |  03/01/2017

2   |  29/01/2017 |  03/02/2017

2   |  04/02/2017 |  05/02/2017

(The format is dd/MM/yyyy)

Now I want to have statistic how many nights in every measurable month was booked so the result should look like:

ID  |   Area   |   Nights

1   |  01/2017 |  5

2   |  02/2017 |  3

```
            var result = (from boo in context.BookingRooms
                      group boo by new { boo.CheckIn.Year, boo.CheckIn.Month } into book
                      orderby book.Key.Year descending, book.Key.Month descending
                      select new NightsPerMonth
                      {
                          Area = book.Key.Month + " / " + book.Key.Year,
                          Nights = ??

                      }).ToList();
```

This is what I have so far, but the problem is that if I group it by check-in, those who was checked in in previous months won't be in group, also if I would be successful in grouping I don't know how to calculate nights just for currently grouped month (avoid counting nights in previous or following month even when Checkout or Checkin are outside of current month) by DbFunctions so LINQ to SQL won't fail.

Thx for any suggestions

Comment: in your first table you have ID 2 show up twice? What does this ID represent?

Comment: @DavidLee its just autoincrement key of table - it doesnt have any further usage

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think your require is quite complicate with a linq query.
I suggest 2 approaches to resolve it.

**Approach 1:**
Here is my sql query to get desires result, you could create store procedure or function to use it.

```
DECLARE @SampleData AS TABLE (Id int IDENTITY (1,1), Checkin Date, Checkout date)

INSERT INTO @SampleData VALUES ('2017-01-01', '2017-01-03'), ('2017-01-29', '2017-02-03'), ('2017-02-04', '2017-02-05')

;WITH temps AS
(
    SELECT CAST(MIN(sd.Checkin) AS Date) AS MinCheckDate, CAST(max(sd.Checkout) AS Date) as MaxCheckDate
    FROM @SampleData sd
)
-- Calculate all months from min-checkin-date to max-checkout-date.
-- By Recursive function
,allMonth AS
(
    SELECT datepart(month,t.MinCheckDate) AS [Month],
          datepart(year, t.MinCheckDate) AS [Year],
          datefromparts(datepart(year, t.MinCheckDate) , datepart(month, t.MinCheckDate) ,1) AS StartMonthDate ,
          EOMONTH(datefromparts(datepart(year, t.MinCheckDate) , datepart(month, t.MinCheckDate) ,1)) AS EndMonthDate
    FROM temps t

    UNION ALL

    SELECT  datepart(month,dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) AS [Month],
          datepart(year, dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) AS [Year],
          datefromparts(datepart(year, dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) , datepart(month, dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) ,1) AS StartMonthDate ,
          EOMONTH(datefromparts(datepart(year, dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) , datepart(month, dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate)) ,1)) AS EndMonthDate
    FROM allMonth am
    CROSS JOIN temps t
    WHERE dateadd(month, 1, am.StartMonthDate) <= t.MaxCheckDate
)
SELECT  CONCAT(am.[Month],'/',am.[Year]) AS Area,
       SUM(
          DATEDIFF(day,
                CAST(IIF(    am.StartMonthDate <= sd.Checkin, sd.Checkin, am.StartMonthDate) AS DATE),
                CAST(IIF(    am.EndMonthDate < sd.Checkout , dateadd(dd, 1,am.EndMonthDate), sd.Checkout)  AS date) -- if Checkout > End of month, then End of month will be calculate as a night 
          ) ) AS Nights
FROM allMonth am
LEFT JOIN @SampleData sd ON am.StartMonthDate BETWEEN sd.Checkin AND sd.Checkout OR am.EndMonthDate BETWEEN sd.Checkin AND sd.Checkout
                       OR sd.Checkin BETWEEN am.StartMonthDate AND am.EndMonthDate OR sd.Checkout BETWEEN am.StartMonthDate AND am.EndMonthDate
GROUP BY am.[Month],am.[Year]
OPTION (MAXRECURSION 0)
```

Demo link: [Rextester](http://rextester.com/SVCAE91115)

**Approach 2:**

You could load all data from BookingRooms table and calculate nights on C#:

```
 var lstBookRooms = (from boo in context.BookingRooms
                            select new BookingRooms
                            {
                                Id = boo.Id,
                                Checkin = boo.CheckIn,
                                Checkout = boo.CheckOut
                            }).ToList();
var lstNightsPerMonth = GetNightsPerMonth(lstBookRooms);
```

Classes

```
public class BookingRooms
{
    public int Id { get; set; }
    public DateTime Checkin { get; set; }
    public DateTime Checkout { get; set; }
}

public class NightsPerMonth
{
    public string Area
    {
        get
        {
            return string.Format("{0}/{1}", Month, Year);
        }
    }
    public int Month { get; set; }

    public int Year { get; set; }

    public int Nights { get; set; }
}
```

And functions

```
public List<NightsPerMonth> GetNightsPerMonth(List<BookingRooms> lstBookRooms)
    {
        if (lstBookRooms == null || lstBookRooms.Count == 0) return null;
        var result = new List<NightsPerMonth>();
        var minCheckin = lstBookRooms.Min(x => x.Checkin);
        var maxCheckout = lstBookRooms.Max(x => x.Checkout);
        var currentMonth = minCheckin;

        while (currentMonth <= maxCheckout)
        {
            result.Add(new NightsPerMonth
            {
                Month = currentMonth.Month,
                Year = currentMonth.Year,
                Nights = GetNumberNightsOfMonth(currentMonth, lstBookRooms)
            });
            currentMonth = currentMonth.AddMonths(1);
        }

        return result;
    }

    private int GetNumberNightsOfMonth(DateTime currentMonth, List<BookingRooms> lstBookRooms)
    {
        var startDateOfMonth = new DateTime(currentMonth.Year, currentMonth.Month, 1);
        var endDateOfMonth = startDateOfMonth.AddMonths(1).AddDays(-1);

        return lstBookRooms.Where(x => IsBookRoom(startDateOfMonth, endDateOfMonth, x.Checkin, x.Checkout))
            .Sum(x => NumberNightsBookRoom(startDateOfMonth, endDateOfMonth, x.Checkin, x.Checkout));
    }

    private bool IsBookRoom(DateTime startDateOfMonth, DateTime endDateOfMonth, DateTime checkin, DateTime checkout)
    {
        if (startDateOfMonth >= checkin && startDateOfMonth <= checkout) return true;
        if (endDateOfMonth >= checkin && endDateOfMonth <= checkout) return true;

        if (checkin >= startDateOfMonth && checkin <= endDateOfMonth) return true;
        if (checkout >= startDateOfMonth && checkout <= endDateOfMonth) return true;

        return false;
    }

    private int NumberNightsBookRoom(DateTime startDateOfMonth, DateTime endDateOfMonth, DateTime checkin, DateTime checkout)
    {
        var startTimeSpan = startDateOfMonth <= checkin ? checkin : startDateOfMonth;

        // if Checkout > End of month, then End of month will be calculate as a night
        var endTimeSpan = endDateOfMonth < checkout ? endDateOfMonth.AddDays(1) : checkout;

        return (endTimeSpan - startTimeSpan).Days;
    }
```

Hope it helps....

Comment: Thx, its not exactly what I was looking for ( its not LINQ) but it solve the issue ! Thank you.